# procedure to take information from one table and write to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Ive got a question which I am completely stumped on. It reads as follows:

*Write a import stored procedure that take information from a table (source) and write it into another table (target).*

Im guessing it would look something like the following:

```
create procedure add_data(@name, @surname)
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT name, surname 
FROM cardholder

INSERT INTO new_table
values (name, surname)
```

Is my logic correct or am I completely missing it?

Comment: have you read this, for example - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#OtherTables ?

Comment: I suggest you check the syntax of the INSERT and SELECT statements. SO isn't the best place to ask homework questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Since you are directly copying from one table to another, you can use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` idiom, like so:

```
create procedure add_data
 @name varchar(100)
 @surname varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN 

 INSERT INTO new_table(name,surname)
 SELECT name, surname 
 FROM cardholder

END
```

Note the 2 changes I made:

1. How you declare the parameters for the SP
2. The `values` clause should consist of the actual values being inserted. Since you are inserting data retrieved from a table rather than fixed values, you use the `select` query instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. try dis

```
create procedure add_data
(
@name varchar(100), 
@surname varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO target
SELECT name, surname 
FROM cardholder

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
create procedure add_data(@name VARCHAR(10), @surname VARCHAR(10))
AS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO new_table(name, surname)
SELECT name, surname 
FROM cardholder
END
```

It would insert data from one table to another so in output what ever the parameters pass it will inserted into new table just plain and simple.

Comment: Try to explain what your code does, and how it would help the OP.

Comment: inserting data from one table to another so in output what ever the parameters pass it will inserted into new table just plain n simple

Comment: I have editted your post and added the data to your post. That is the way your post should look like. :) This way, it would attract the viewer and you'll get +1 votes more. Most of the users don't look at Commentary, they just look at the post. :) Good luck!